# Fold list to pair with destructuring assignment in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, fold, destructuring

I try to get multiple results from a folding operation on a list of characters and use a destructuring assignment to both values to their own variables afterwards. But this seems to result in an exception by the kotlin compiler:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Don't know how to generate outer expression for class <closure-Test$1>
```

Strangely (to me) without the destructuring, this works as intended. Here is an example:

```
val fstSec = "fst"

val (fst, snd) = "this is a test for folding to pair"
    .toCharArray()
    .fold(Pair(0, 0), { sumPair, char ->
        when (fstSec) {
            "fst" -> Pair(sumPair.first + char.toInt()*2, sumPair.second + char.toInt())
            "snd" -> Pair(sumPair.first + char.toInt(), sumPair.second + char.toInt()*2)
            else -> throw RuntimeException("exception")
        }
    })

println("( $fst , $snd )")
```

This results in the exception.

```
val fstSec = "fst"

val pair = "this is a test for folding to pair"
    .toCharArray()
    .fold(Pair(0, 0), { sumPair, char ->
        when (fstSec) {
            "fst" -> Pair(sumPair.first + char.toInt()*2, sumPair.second + char.toInt())
            "snd" -> Pair(sumPair.first + char.toInt(), sumPair.second + char.toInt()*2)
            else -> throw RuntimeException("exception")
        }
    })

println("( ${pair.first} , ${pair.second} )")
```

This one works as expected, and the only thing I removed was the destructuring. Strangely, if I remove the inner *when* (and replace it by a *Pair* constructor only), the code works both times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Please report it to [kotl.in/issue](https://kotl.in/issue)

Comment: By the way, I tried to compile the first sample with Kotlin 1.2.10, and it worked just fine. It might have already been fixed. What is the Kotlin version that you use?

Comment: Kotlin version 1.2.0 (JRE 1.8.0_144-b01)

Comment: I'm using Kotlin 1.2 and this worked fine when I wrapped the whole thing in a function. Otherwise it complains that destructuring is only supported for local variables.

Comment: Maybe it had been worth mentioning, that I used this in a kts file. Haven't yet tried when compiling it (does/should this make a difference?)

Comment: @razr, yep, I could reproduce it with a `.kts` file, this really seems to make the difference.

Comment: Ok, created a new issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22029

Comment: @hotkey could you create an answer, so I'll accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Kotlin Script compilation.

Thanks [@razr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6828631/razr) for reporting it: [KT-22029](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22029)